# How to reduce gradle build time to 2min in android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Guys i am having a night mare with the gradle build time it takes forever to build, i have gone through all the available solution here on stack Overflow nothing is really working for me, though i am not an expert with gradle a real need your help.

**Please take a look at build.gradle**

[Gradle.build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoGuo.png)

And gradle.properties
[Gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKzCu.png)

What is wrong, or is there any other settings i am missing?

Your help will be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Do not post incomplete screenshots. Edit your question and post the text of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: it looks like you have A LOT of dependencies, the more you have the longer it takes to build

Answer (score 1):

The first step to debugging build time issues is to understand where the time is being spent. I would recommend that you add "--profile" to your Gradle command and look at the report to see which tasks are taking most of the time. Gradle's [Build Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/setup/step-1) is also pretty useful for this purpose.

Assuming you are using Android Gradle plugin 2.1.2 or later, I would also suggest you remove javaMaxHeap under dexOptions, and then set the amount of memory you give to Gradle to 4GB in your gradle.properties file. You want to make sure your build is using dexInProcess because dexing is typically the step that takes the longest.

A lot of times when we have seen pathologically long builds is when there is a lot of memory pressure on the system. You want to make sure you don't have a lot of other apps open at the same time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: still couldn't help, i tried to remove the JavaMaxHeap its still, i have realised that gradle is using too much memory, still don't know to solve that.

Comment: What version of Android Studio and Android Gradle plugin are you using? Please try the latest 2.2 Beta.

Comment: i am using the latest android studio 2.1.2 and 2.10 gradle, also i haved added the org.gradle.configureondemand=true on my gradle properties and now its taking about 30 min to build